# sql query/entity framework query not returning distinct values on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a query I am running on two Tables (Table Customer and Table Vendor). On Table Customer I may have multiple rows of similar records. I am joining the two tables using the parameters below, however I noticed instances of Table Vendor Id duplicates in the query result. I am guessing this is because I have multiple similar records on Table Customer. Please can someone assist me with the right query to use to get distinct ID values on the join? Note that I am using this on entity framework core for a project. See query used on entity framework converted to sql below

```
SQL

select distinct * from Vendor e inner join Customer d on e.account = d.Cod_account
where (e.ActionStatus = 'Pending' and d.ActionStatus = 'Pending') and (d.Amt = e.Amount)
and (e.UploadTime = '05:00pm') and (e.Uploaddate = d.Calldate) order by d.Amt desc

ENTITY FRAMEWORK

await (from  e in _dbc.Vendor join d in _dbc.Customer on e.account equals d.Cod_account 
where (e.ActionStatus == "Pending" && d.ActionStatus == "Pending") && (d.Amt == e.Amount)
&& (e.UploadTime == uploadtime) && (e.Uploaddate == d.Calldate)
orderby d.Amt descending
      select new CustomerVend
       {
          Customer = d,
          Vendor = e
       }).Take(2000).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT ID` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT *`

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. But please how do I convert it to entity framework? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know E-F or ASP.net.

Comment: Please stop shouting

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your LINQ query. `Distinct` should be placed before `Take`.

```
var query = 
   from e in _dbc.Vendor 
   join d in _dbc.Customer on e.account equals d.Cod_account 
   where e.ActionStatus == "Pending" 
      && d.ActionStatus == "Pending"
      && d.Amt == e.Amount
      && e.UploadTime == uploadtime 
      && e.Uploaddate == d.Calldate
   orderby d.Amt descending
   select new CustomerVend
   {
      Customer = d,
      Vendor = e
   }

var result = await query.Distinct().Take(2000).ToListAsync();
```